# Vue 3 - Determine if a given component instance is a descendant of another component instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In a Vue application, I have a need to check whether a given component instance A has a specific other component instance B (identified by uid) as a descendant.

In Vue 2, the way I went about this was looping over the `$children` of component A, over the children of those, etc. until finding a match for the uid. However, `$children` is removed from Vue 3, so this method will not work:

```
    /**
     * Checks if component "componentB" is a child or descendant of the component "componentA".
     * @returns A boolean.
     */
    private recursiveChildCheck(componentA: object, componentBUid: string) {
        //@ts-ignore
        if(String(componentA.$.uid) === String(componentBUid)) {
            return true;
        }

        // componentA.$children does not exist!
        let children = componentA.$children;
        if (children && (children.length > 0)) {
            return children.some((child: object) => {
                if (this.recursiveChildCheck(child, componentBUid)) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The commonly suggested solutions (`refs` or `slots`) depend on knowing the template structure of each parent component, which is not realistic when traversing the tree down from any component.

A close solution I found was [using `componentA.$.subTree.children`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396541/9799381), but that seemed to get stuck on `Transition`s, which appear to have an empty `subTree`.

So, any suggestions either on an alternative for `$children` or on identifying whether a component is a descendant would be very welcome.